# Using .htaccess to access content outside of website root

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Maybe this question was already asked before but I didn't know how to search for it. So I have a URL like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/archive/page.html
```

The domain is showing to folder A, the archive subfolder is in folder B:

```
/
/A (website root)
/B/archive/page.html
```

What do I have to write in the .htaccess file to be able to use the above URL?

The goal of this is to install a new website in A without putting pages of the old site in B that still have to be kept into the new website folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scenario 1**

If `A` and `B` are not under the same web root, you will need to use an [alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) and define a directory block for the target directory. This cannot be done in an .htaccess file, but can be set in the server or vhost configuration:

```
Alias "/archive" "/path/to/B/archive"
<Directory "/path/to/B/archive">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The `Options` and `AllowOverride` directives should be added as necessary.

**Scenario 2**

If `A` and `B` are sub-directories under the web root `/`, then the below .htaccess entry should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?archive(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/B/archive$1 [PT,L]
```

That should also pass through any query strings in the URL.

**Added: Scenario 3**

If you need `/archive` to map to `/B/archive` while allowing rewrites to files under `/B/`, the following configurations should work.

First we create the alias to map `/B` into the web root, making it accessible to rewrite rules:

```
Alias "/B" "/path/to/B"
<Directory "/path/to/B">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then we use the following rewrite rules to map `/archive` to `/B/archive`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?archive(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/B/archive$1 [PT,L]
```

Any other files from `/B` that you want to map into `/` (e.g. `/B/page.html` served as `/page.html`) can be done by adding a rule like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/?page\.html$ /B/page.html [L]
```

This pretty much combines Scenarios 1 and 2 to get the desired effect.

**Added: Scenario 4**

This just occurred to me, but if the files you want served from `/B` don't already exist in the root folder `/A` you could just map every request for files not in `/A` to `/B` instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/B/
RewriteCond %(DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %(DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /B%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

This basically does the following:

- Checks that the request doesn't already start with `/B` to prevent loops
- Checks that the request doesn't match a file or directory
- Rewrite the request to begin with `/B`, and serve that resource, if it exists

That will handle the `/archive` case as well. You'll still need the alias from scenario 3. Also note that if the requested resource doesn't exist in `/A` or `/B` you'll still get a `404`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For me scenario 1 is relevant. What if `/archive` is not a folder but a file? So e.g. `page.html` is in the root of B, but has to be accessed with `mydomain.com/page.html`?

Comment: So there are files under `B` that you want to access without the `/archive` prefix? In that case if it's only one or two files, you can add a rule like: `RewriteRule ^/?page\.html$ /B/page.html [L]` for each one. That would get tedious if there are a lot of files you want to do that for. Are you trying to redirect a bunch of files with the same extension, or same file prefix? Regex matching would probably help in that case.

Comment: It's just about 15 html and php files, so not much effort... Hm, but you wrote before that rewrite rules are only possible if `A` and `B` are under the same web root, what they aren't in my case...

Comment: Rewrite rules by themselves couldn't, but using an alias to map an external directory into the web root allows you to target it with rewrite rules. I'll edit my answer to provide a third solution using both that should satisfy your scenario.