# php / htaccess - serve files from another directory outside directoryroot?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Imagine site is `https://www.example.com` and it maps to `/var/www/example.com/public`

I have a typical index.php router to feed any request within example.com through index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Can I serve files in the `other` or `thing` directories from another location on the server (outside example.com's directory root), such as `/var/www/othersite.org/public/other/`?

```
RewriteRule ^(other|thing)/?(.*) /var/www/othersite.org/public/$1/$2 [L]
```

I get a 'unable to process this request' error.

Comment: Symlink or Alias would be the preferred methods, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#outside In the .htaccess context, such a rewrite would not be possible, according to https://serverfault.com/a/1088628

Comment: On a side note, you don't need mod_rewrite at all to have a router script. `FallbackResource` does the same exact thing and doesn't drain your will to live.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570085/accessing-files-outside-the-document-root-with-apache, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131562/serving-images-from-outside-of-document-root, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630369/using-htaccess-to-access-content-outside-of-website-root, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325467/apache-symlink-to-a-folder-outside-of-web-root, ... OR, since your question is tagged PHP, maybe you want to use PHP to `require` or `include` the files, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713980/php-get-file-outside-of-document-root

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing files outside the document root with Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570085/accessing-files-outside-the-document-root-with-apache)